# In Graph Theory, if $G$ is a graph, then what does $\Delta(G)$ mean?

Tags: graph-theory, notation

I know that in Graph Theory, if we have a graph $G = (V, E)$, then $\delta(G)$ means the $\min d(v)$ over all $v\in V$, but what about $\Delta(G)$? What does it mean?

Comment: I know that $\delta(G)$ and $\Delta(G)$ are the minimum and maximum degree in the graph $G$, but what is $d(v)$? Is that an abbreviation for $\deg(v)$, the degree of the vertex $v$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Typically $\Delta$ is used to denote the maximum degree of $G$, i.e., the largest degree out of all of the degrees. To be absolutely sure, check the source you are reading. If it doesn't define it, assume this.